# What means the boundary of a space

Tags: general-topology, notation, terminology

By definition topological spaces are clopen and then their boundaries are empty, but for example, is said that the boundary of the closed unit interval is it's two endpoints a so on.
whath is the meanining of "boundary" in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two notions of boundary in mathematics. One is the [boundary of a subset of a topological space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_(topology)), and it is a relative notion: it takes as input two objects, a topological space and a subset of it. *As a subset of $\mathbb{R}$*, the boundary of $[0, 1]$ is its endpoints. (However, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$, for example, the boundary of $[0, 1]$ is $[0, 1]$. Again, relative.)

There is also the boundary of a [manifold with boundary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary), which takes as input one object, a manifold with boundary. *As a manifold with boundary*, the boundary of $[0, 1]$ is also its endpoints.

Comment: oh thats clarifier thanks